# When is it okay to use multiple devise models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

When is it okay to use multiple devise models?

I have 3 types of users - users, vendors and admin. Vendors have a bunch more fields than users so I want to have separate tables for them. Users can sign up and sign in using facebook (vendors cannot). And users and vendors share the same sign-in page/form.

I started with multiple devise models, got confused how to handle a single sign-in page, and then read a lot here about using polymorphic associations and STI instead of discrete models. I'm still confused as to when each approach should be used and what would work better here... i know its a little vague, any advise would be great though, or any good links..

Users also fill out a bunch of extra fields when they sign up - even through facebook. How can I keep track of those fields for an omniauth login? (and should I use devise for this or something like omniauth identity..?)

Thanks for looking at this! I'm a rails newbie setting up authentication first time, really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the case it is recommended to separate or use a single model. The alternatives:

1. Use separate models, override the controllers, so firstly you check if the record match in User, and if it doesn't match try with Vendor
2. Use a single model for storing User and Vendor, use a boolean (a string if it is a polymorphic association)  to check the kind of user, and add related models in order to store the additional fields

I think option #1 is easier but bigger, and option #2 is a little bit difficult but shorter.

Also, it would be a good idea to separate the models because User connects to FB and Vendor no, it represents a lot of differences.

In another way, the searches will be faster using option #2, because it will be only 1 query, and the table will be light because it will not contain the specific fields for users and vendors; you also have to consider this in order to make a decision.

For Admin you can follow a similar criteria.

Check this out: https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook